# Player doesnt move slower

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make an undertale fan game and I tried making it so that when you press `x` you move slower. But the player still moves at the same speed.

I tried just making it so when you press `x` you dont run the "Normal" Movement but the "Slow" Movement function. But the player still doesn't move slower.

Here's the code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    //Physics
    Rigidbody2D rb;
    //Serialized Fields
    [SerializeField] float MovementSpeed = 5f;
    private Vector3 startingPos = Vector3.zero;
    [SerializeField]float ActiveMoveSpeed;
    float SlowSpeed = 1f;

    public void SetHeart()
    {
        transform.position = startingPos;
    }

    void Start()
    {
        SetHeart();
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        ActiveMoveSpeed = MovementSpeed;
    }



    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.X))
        {
            Debug.Log("Pressing x");
            SlowMovement();
        }
        else
        {
            Movement();
        }
    }
    void Movement()
    {
        float HorizontalInput = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(HorizontalInput * ActiveMoveSpeed, rb.velocity.y);
        ActiveMoveSpeed = MovementSpeed;

        float VerticalInput = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, VerticalInput * ActiveMoveSpeed);
        ActiveMoveSpeed = MovementSpeed;
    }
    void SlowMovement()
    {
        float HorizontalInputSlow = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(HorizontalInputSlow * SlowSpeed, rb.velocity.y);

        float VerticalInputSlow = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, VerticalInputSlow * SlowSpeed);
        
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Surely you only want to set the velocity once?

Comment: @BugFinder While technically inefficient, this method shouldn't cause errors since the second assignment would be pulling the values from the first assignment. (Also, don't call me Shirley.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.X))
```

`GetKeyDown` only returns true *once* on the first frame when the button is pressed ([Documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetKeyDown.html)).

Use `GetKey` instead to check the current status of the button. ([Documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetKey.html))